# Synapse notebook not able to read/write to dedicated sql pool or ADLS2

Tags: apache-spark, azure-synapse

We are moving to a new subscription due to a company break up and are currently setting up and testing a new synapse workspace that needs to mirror the old one. Currently having issues with our notebooks reading and/or writing data to/from our dedicated Sql pool or even the data lake. Simple example statement below works fine on our old subscription, but gives an error on current one when it gets to the display(product) statement, something to do with using a temporary folder in the spark pool?

product = (spark.read.synapsesql("database.schema.VW_Product").select("PID", "ProductCode", "DumpProduct")
)

display(product)

Error:
An error occurred while calling o3949.showString.
: com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.SQLAnalyticsConnectorException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed as the path name 'abfss://config@.dfs.core.windows.net/synapse/workspaces//sparkpools/sparkAdam/sparkpoolinstances//livysessions/2023/07/11/1/tempdata/SQLAnalyticsConnectorStaging/application_1689070512839_0002/az4yCXuWzHic103b969fa2048d19cdef565df71dc5c.tbl' could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory.

Any advice would be appreciated. The link indicates to me it is something to do with the spark pool. If I use print(product) then I get the schema of the dataframe, which indicates that it has been created?

Many thanks

Adam

Comment: What permission do you and/or the Managed Identity of the Synapse workspace have on the storage account?

Comment: Yes this seems like a permission issue since it cannot see the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below approach using the spark.read.synapsesql method.

```
Import the required libraries
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder
.appName("Write to Dedicated SQL Pool")
.getOrCreate()
server="xxxxx.sql.azuresynapse.net"
database = "dedicated sqlpool"
user = "sqladminuser"
password = "Welcome@1"
jdbcUrl = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{server};database={database};user={user};password={password}" 
tableName = "dbo.Ext_Employees"
data = [(1, 'John', 25), (2, 'Jane', 30)] 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "Name", "Age"])
df.write
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", jdbcUrl)
.option("dbtable", tableName)
.option("createTableColumnTypes", "ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50), Age INT")
.mode("overwrite")
.save()
Emp_df = (spark.read.synapsesql("database.schema.Ext_Employees").select("ID", "Name", "Age") )
display(Emp_df)
```

**Error:**
[image]

- Regarding the error that you received  check. Specified path exists and is a directory. If it does not exist, create the directory and try again.
- Make sure you have necessary permissions to create files in the specified directory. If not, grant the necessary permissions and try again.
- The error message  you have provided indicates that the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT` statement failed because the specified path
  name
  `abfss://config@<storage_account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/synapse/workspaces/<workspace_name>/sparkpools/<spark_pool_name>/sparkpoolinstances/<instance_id>/livysessions/<session_id>/<temp_folder>/SQLAnalyticsConnectorStaging/application_<application_id>/<temp_table_name>.tbl` could not be used for export.
- For more information about [Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Connector for Apache Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export?tabs=scala,scala1,scala2,scala3,scala4,scala5)
- More about how to [Use external tables with Synapse SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop)

Thank you, @Sidney Cirqueira for the article. Know More about [Writing data using Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool Connector for Apache Spark](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/writing-data-using-azure-synapse-dedicated-sql-pool-connector/ba-p/3535930)

Comment: No, the synapsesql method is fine.  It’s a built-in method specifically for writing to dedicated sql pools.  This is most likely permissions, eg Storage Blob Data Contributor